# Can mana generated by Rosheen Meanderer be used to pay for non-X components of costs that contain X?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The mana from the giant [Rosheen Meanderer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rosheen%20Meanderer) can only be used for spells with X, but it does not have to only pay the X cost. So, for instance, you can tap an island and the giant and cast [Stroke of Genius](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stroke%20of%20Genius) for X = 2.

I'm pretty sure it works like that, just need confirmation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's often helpful, as @PhilipKendall noticed, to check the [rulings under the card in Gatherer](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Rosheen%20Meanderer#ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_MainContent_SubContent_SubContent_rulingsRow):

> You can spend mana generated by Rosheen on any part of a cost that contains {X}. You're not limited to spending it only on the {X} part.

So yes, you can cast a Stroke of Genius (mana cost X2U) for X = 2.